# Jasmine Testing - Priority

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

Is there a way in Jasmine to define the proirity of the failure of the test?

For example, a service which is now 500'ing is worse than simple content just not displaying on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not the way unit or integration tests work. Ether a test is failing or not. And you should not have any failing test in your suite, otherwise the whole approach would not make any sense.